# C++ undefined reference to `__imp_...' when using the D++ library

Tags: c++, g++, c++17, linker-errors, d++

I read through a lot of questions with similiar issues here, most of them are all because they forgot to implement something defined in a header file. But my problem, according to the errors, are from the DPP library. I went throught a few of the header files of the library, every definiton the error mentioned has a body. My compile command is `g++ -std=c++17 -O3 -m64 -Wa,-mbig-obj -I include -o ./bin/bot -Wall <all the files>`. The DPP folder is placed under `include`.

Any directions would be very helpful.

Comment: please share actual full error message